# acroread pdf to postscript conversion too slow

Tags: bash, pdf, postscript, adobe-reader

I am converting pdf file in postscript file using acroread command.

The conversion is successfull but it is too slow and almost uses 100% of CPU,

because of this my application hangs for some time and thus no user is able to do

anything.

The code i am using is:-

processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("bash","-c","acroread -toPostScript -size "+width+"x"+height+" -optimizeForSpeed sample.pdf");

pp = processBuilder.start();

pp.waitFor();

Is there a way to speed up the process and make it to use less percentage of CPU.

Please help!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you start by using strace on the command line to diagnose the problem. 
    strace -tt -f acroread -toPostScript -size 1000x2500 -optimizeForSpeed sample.pdf.

I suspect you may find it spends a lot of time reading font files.

If you have a choice then poppler or Xpdf or even ghostscript should be more supported and performant options, especially considering acroread is now [unsupported on linux](https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2013-1402.html").